# Reasonable practice for existing db with 75 tables

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm creating a new visual studio web site using MVC4/webapi that will go against a database of 75 preexisting tables (not perfect in terms of foreign keys, etc.).  I'm thinking that I will create an ado.net entity data model and select all my tables. then, when my tables change I will do the "update model".

With my linq2sql projects, I always ran sqlmetal against all my tables all the time to keep things in sync and that worked fairly well.

Is my plan to have all my tables in one ado.net entity data model reasonable? what pitfalls might I run into?  Is it better to have lots of ado.net entity data models?  I've tried having multiple ado.net entity models in other projects and I seem to constantly be getting my connection strings doubled in my web.config.

I did do a search on SO and did not find any discussions that directly addressed my concern.

Comment: Which version of .NET, Visual Studio and Entity Framework are you using? The tooling has advanced substantially between versions. It will greatly help give you an accurate answer for us to know that.

Comment: I'm planning on using the latest bits that are included in vs2013 when it ships. I think that is EF5

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I believe that will be EF6.

Comment: VS2013 actually supports both EF5 and EF6.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed your plan, you would miss out on an opportunity to have an entity model simpler than your database model:

- Your application almost certainly doesn't need all 75 tables.
- You would be missing the opportunity to consider a series of 1-1 tables as a single entity
- You would be missing the opportunity to use inheritance in your model
- You would be missing the opportunity to keep junction tables out of your model

You would be losing one of the greatest advantages of Entity Framework over LINQ to SQL: it does not need to stay one-to-one with the database.

Comment: One issue I have not figured out how to solve which is stopping me from wanting to make multiple models is that when I create new ado.net models, it seems to create a new entry in my web.config for each.  Then, I end up with my connection string repeated over and over.  Is there a best practices way to avoid that?  I looked at doing it in code and it seemed overly complex